# Helps needed for implementing a button action in html page

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

Problem analysis:

When I'm clicking a submit button of my html form the function related to the button is called and it does its work.after completing the work a mail notification is sent which is consuming too much time.after that a confirmation message is displayed on the same html (without using ajax i,e page is refreshed).

My question and need:

I want to avoid the user by clicking the submit button a number of times in confusion during the waiting period of sending mails.so I'm thinking to disable the button after it is pressed once.

1) How to do it?

2) Can you please suggest any other technique to achieve this goal without disabling the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I belive that this will work:

```
onclick="this.disabled=true"
```

Comment: `onclick="this.disabled=true; this.value='please wait...';"`

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply hide the button, again using javascript in the onclick event, but this time add a style, such as "display:none", and then the button will not be displayed for the user to click on at all.

Note: This may be disturbing to some users. Developer discretion is advised.